# Gradients don't agree with finite differences

Tags: c++, statistics, modeling

I'm building a statistical model where I need to take the grad of a log(density). The log density is of a row vector z_i, and takes the following form:

[image: log(density) of a row vector z_i]

for which I calculate the grad (with respect to the elements of z_i) to be

[image: grad(log(density)) of z_i with respect to the elements of z_i]

In c++ the log(density) looks like this:

```
double ldzi_nofirefly(int i, arma::mat Alabels, arma::mat z, arma::mat connecteds, int connectednum, arma::mat disconnecteds, int disconnectednum, arma::vec tau, arma::mat gaussmat){
  double res = 0;
  double square = dot(z.row(i), z.row(i));
  for(int j =0; j < connectednum; ++j){
    res -= gaussmat(i,connecteds(i,j)) * dot(z.row(i), z.row(connecteds(i,j)));
  }
  res += 0.5 * gaussmat(i,i) * square;

  //no edge dyads
  for(int j = 0; j < disconnectednum; ++j){
    res += log(1.0 - tau[Alabels(i, disconnecteds(i,j))] * exp(-0.5 * (square + dot(z.row(disconnecteds(i,j)), z.row(disconnecteds(i,j))) - 2.0 * dot(z.row(disconnecteds(i,j)), z.row(i)))));
  }
  return(res);
}
```

and the grad(log(density)) looks like this

```
arma::rowvec grad_log(int i, arma::rowvec z_row, arma::mat gaussmat, arma::mat z, arma::mat connecteds, int connectednum, arma::mat disconnecteds, int disconnectednum, arma::vec tau, arma::mat Alabels){
  // use z_row to create an output vector
  arma::rowvec res(z.n_cols, fill::zeros);
  // edges dyads
  for(int j = 0; j < connectednum; ++j){
    res -= gaussmat(i, connecteds(i, j)) * z.row(connecteds(i, j));
  }
  res += gaussmat(i, i) * z_row;

  //no edge dyads
  for(int j = 0; j < disconnectednum; ++j){
    arma::rowvec difference = z_row - z.row(disconnecteds(i, j));

    res += ((tau[Alabels(i, disconnecteds(i,j))] * exp(-0.5 * dot(difference, difference))) / (1.0 - tau[Alabels(i, disconnecteds(i,j))] * exp(-0.5 * dot(difference, difference)))) * difference;
  }
  return(res);
}
```

where z.row(i) in the first function corresponds to z_row in the second; both corresponding to the vector z_i. Something was up with the gradient calculation, so I used the method of finite differences ([finite differences wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Multivariate_finite_differences)) to approximate it. The method of finite differences produced the correct result but the grad(log(density)) does not. The finite differences function is as follows:

```
arma::rowvec fin_diff(int i, arma::rowvec z_row, arma::mat gaussmat, arma::mat z, arma::mat connecteds, int connectednum, arma::mat disconnecteds, int disconnectednum, arma::vec tau, arma::mat Alabels){
  // use z_row to create an output vector
  arma::rowvec res = z_row;
  res = res.zeros();
  int d = z.n_cols;

  // calculate each component of the gradient using the method of finite differences
  for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j){
    arma::rowvec positive_perturbation = z_row;
    arma::rowvec negative_perturbation = z_row;
    positive_perturbation[j] += pow(10, -10);
    negative_perturbation[j] -= pow(10, -10);

    arma::mat pos_z = z;
    arma::mat neg_z = z;
    pos_z.row(i) = positive_perturbation;
    neg_z.row(i) = negative_perturbation;

    res[j] = ldzi_nofirefly(i, Alabels, pos_z, connecteds, connectednum, disconnecteds, disconnectednum, tau, gaussmat) - ldzi_nofirefly(i, Alabels, neg_z, connecteds, connectednum, disconnecteds, disconnectednum, tau, gaussmat);
    res[j] /= 2 * pow(10, -10);
  }
  return(res);
}
```

I do not understand why the finite difference function, and the grad(log(density)) function produce different results. Could somebody help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: your images are not readable in dark mode. (I can change the mode of course...)

Comment: Sorry! Do you want me to change the colour of the font?

Comment: I just wanted to tell you, because others might have the same problem. No transparent background would fix it I guess. Imho the question has other (more severe) problems that make it difficult/impossible to answer.

Comment: If I understand you right, you are asking why two different methdos yield different results, but you only show one of them. One would have to look at both to see why they are different. Also I have the feeling that this a question about maths more than C++ code

Comment: On a very cursory glance, check your boundary conditions - they look funny to me.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Scheff, the images are jpegs now :) I'm fairly confident about the maths but I'm open to correction :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean @Bathsheba

Comment: Max, the derivative of the log term doesn't look right to me. Isn't d/dx log(f(x)) = (d/dx f(x))/f(x) ? The term you show doesn't seem to have that form. Also, about debugging the calculated derivative, maybe you can compute the terms separately and compare them (i.e. term1 = ..., term2 = ..., term3 = ..., grad = term1 + term2 + term3) to see which one or ones are not matching the finite difference approximation.

Comment: Another idea is to let x = vector of length 1, which should simplify things somewhat.

Comment: Hey @RobertDodier, the derivative of the log term is simplified in the mathematical expression, but you can see its equivalent 'non-simplified' form in the grad_log function